# Как создать metabox при определенных правах (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress

Функция получения роли пользователя get_current_user_role, а функция metatest_init проверяет роль пользователя на "Администратор" и создает метабок. Но что-то тут не работает....Помогите разобраться что

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metatest_init');

function metatest_init()
{
   $current_user_role = get_current_user_role( $user );
   if ($current_user_role == 'Administrator') {    

    add_meta_box('metatest',
        'MetaTest-параметры поста',
        'metatest_showup',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high',
        'default');
   };
}

function get_current_user_role( $current_user ) {
global $wp_roles;

$roles = $current_user->roles;
$role = array_shift( $roles );

return $wp_roles->role_names[$role];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в

```
   $current_user_role = get_current_user_role( $user );
   if ($current_user_role == 'Administrator') {
```

Во первых в `get_current_user_role` не нужно передавать переменную. По умолчанию это текущий юзер.
Во вторых синтаксис получения данных неверный. См [документацию](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) или [по-русски](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_current_user).
Ну и в главных. Лучше проверять не название роли, возможности - [Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator). Для этого есть [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) ([по-русски](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_user_can))